# meteor adding android platform error

Tags: android, meteor, atmosphere.js

I am new to MeteorJS. I was trying to learn the WhatsApp clone mentioned on the Meteor webpage, when I try adding the Android, I am facing the following error:

```
meteor --verbose add-platform android
C:\Users\Shyam\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.4_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Command failed: D:\Self Courses\meteor projects\whatsapp\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\ios\cordova\version
'D:\Self' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
    at ChildProcess.exitCallback (C:\tools\utils\processes.js:151:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Does anybody have any idea of what could the issue be?

The Java SDK is installed:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I have installed Android through Android Studio. But I am unable to view the SDK folder within the `programfiles/android/` directory.

edit:
now this issue is been resolved. Im facing another:

```
D:\whatsapp>meteor npm install ionic-scripts --save
whatsapp@ D:\whatsapp
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@^1.5.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-animate@^1.5.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-sanitize@^1.5.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-ui-router@^0.2.13
`-- ionic-scripts@1.3.2
  `-- ionic-sdk@1.2.4

npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular@^1.5.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular-animate@^1.5.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular-sanitize@^1.5.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular-ui-router@^0.2.13 but none was installed.
```

how to add the angular packages mentioned.
I tried in atmosphere to search for angular 1.5.3
What are the packages that needs to be installed

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the path you are using, so you must escape it or enclose the path between quotes.

Comment: ya, I thought of that too. But I did not use the path in the cmd, but I changed my directory and went inside that path and then gave the command. I thought the system would have handled that

Comment: ya, Its working when I create a meteor project within a path that does not have spaces in it. I do not know how to mention the file path in the meteor api as its not mentioned in the docs. But this places restrictions that my folder has to be present only within a tree of directories that does not contain space chars in its name, which is a bad user experience